# Is there a way to document few datasets in the same R file when compiling documentation with roxygen2 package in R?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am wondering if there is a possibility to have 1 help page in documentation in R for more that 1 dataset? And I am wondering if `@alias` is possible in that case?

More or less I would like to document 3 datasets like this

```
#' 
#' title
#'
#' description
#' 
#' @source \url{url}
#' @alias
"data1"
"data2"
"data3"
```

**EDIT**

The solution is to have the same @rdname and @name like this:

```
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @aliases ACC.clinical,BLCA.clinical,BRCA.clinical,CESC.clinical,CHOL.clinical,COAD.clinical,COADREAD.clinical,DLBC.clinical,ESCA.clinical,FPPP.clinical,GBM.clinical,GBMLGG.clinical,HNSC.clinical,KICH.clinical,KIPAN.clinical,KIRC.clinical,KIRP.clinical,LAML.clinical,LGG.clinical,LIHC.clinical,LUAD.clinical,LUSC.clinical,MESO.clinical,OV.clinical,PAAD.clinical,PCPG.clinical,READ.clinical,SKCM.clinical,STAD.clinical,STES.clinical,TGCT.clinical,THCA.clinical,THYM.clinical,UCEC.clinical,UCS.clinical,UVM.clinical
#'
"ACC.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#'
"BRCA.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#' 
"BLCA.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#' 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible, although I haven't done that. Try reading this http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-data-sets .

Alias should be possible in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have the same @rdname and @name like this:

```
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @aliases ACC.clinical,BLCA.clinical,BRCA.clinical,CESC.clinical,CHOL.clinical,COAD.clinical,COADREAD.clinical,DLBC.clinical,ESCA.clinical,FPPP.clinical,GBM.clinical,GBMLGG.clinical,HNSC.clinical,KICH.clinical,KIPAN.clinical,KIRC.clinical,KIRP.clinical,LAML.clinical,LGG.clinical,LIHC.clinical,LUAD.clinical,LUSC.clinical,MESO.clinical,OV.clinical,PAAD.clinical,PCPG.clinical,READ.clinical,SKCM.clinical,STAD.clinical,STES.clinical,TGCT.clinical,THCA.clinical,THYM.clinical,UCEC.clinical,UCS.clinical,UVM.clinical
#'
"ACC.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#'
"BRCA.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#' 
"BLCA.clinical"
#' @name clinical
#' @rdname clinical
#' @format NULL
#' 
...
```